# Search in Database, output in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have a Database with 2 Tables. Now i want to search for Values in my Databases.

[image]

I use this GUI so the "User" can give Information to the Textbox and the searched Values should shown in my Datagridview

I use this Code:

```
    private void TB_MSGHeadline_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (TB_MSGHeadline.Text.Equals(""))
            {

            }
            else
            {

                    DataView dv = new DataView(table);
                    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("MessageHeadline LIKE '%{0}%'", TB_MSGHeadline.Text);

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception i)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + i);
        }
    }
```

**Fill the DataGridview**

```
        private void GetData(string selectCommand)
    {
        //Creating a new data adapter based on the specified query.
        dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, ConnectionString);

        //Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and 
        //delete commands based on selectCommand. These are used to
        //update the Database.
        SqlCommandBuilder CommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder();

        //Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        dataAdapter.Fill(table);
        BindingSource1.DataSource = table;
    }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1;
        GetData("SELECT * FROM Tabelle1");
    }
```

(Found it in a video but dont work for my problem)

But i get the Error, that the row "MessageHeadline" wasnt found 
[image]

So i want to know, how can i make a `LIKE`  search for my SQL Database?

Comment: Where's your SQL command?

Comment: You apply a condition to the RowFilter property of a DataView derived from the variable `table`. Are you sure that this table contains a column named `MessageHeadline`?

Comment: There is no SQL Command ... the Connection stay there , because i try some other things, which dont work

Comment: Use the debugger. Put a breakpoint on the RowFilter line. Then move the mouse over the table variable. You could see an icon that allows you to see the content of the variable 'table'. Do you have the column required by the setting of the RowFilter property?

Comment: @Steve Yep I see and if i go over and look for the content i see, that  `Table` is empty ... !

Comment: Then you should investigate how this table variable has been defined and why it doesn't refer to the original one used to fill the grid

Comment: Yes,in my first `Form` my Table get content but not in my second Form :/   I will look for this

Comment: OK , It´s solved !   I have in my Method  `Datatable table = new Datatable();`  and another SAME var as global but VS 13 never said it to me that there are 2 same var ... THX! :)